# JQuery conflict for contextMenu

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

i have a web page with
Import code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/ContextMenu.js"></script>
```

HTML code:

```
<span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span>
```

jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
           copy: {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
            }}
        }
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })    
});
```

If I use it, in console comes the following error message:
**$.contextMenu is not a function**

If I add:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

it doesn't work too.
But if I use **jQuery.noConflict()**  it works,but in console comes the following error message: **$.metisMenu is not a function**

I use a template called [Admin2](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/)
and I see the example of ContextMenu.js called [ExampleContextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html)
How could I solve? I do not know.
*I believe that the jquery version is too old*

Comment: Can you create JSFiddle?

Comment: You can see the example at the link:
https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html